# Woocommerce Cart Message if shipping required

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have this code to add two lines on the Woocommerce cart and checkout pages, however I only want it to show if shipping is required. I suspect $needs_shipping might need to be in there somewhere but no idea where.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total', 'promote_free_shipping');
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'promote_free_shipping');
function promote_free_shipping() {
if (WC()->cart->cart_contents_total) {
    $total = WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal();
                    echo '<tr class="promote_free_shipping"><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">We aim to dispatch your order within 2 working days.</td></tr>';

    // Tell them how much to add to the cart to get free shipping.
    $free_shipping_threshold = 50;
    if ($total < $free_shipping_threshold) {
            echo '<tr class="promote_free_shipping"><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">For free delivery add <strong>'.wc_price($free_shipping_threshold-$total).'</strong> to your cart (excluding tour tickets).</td></tr>'; } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replaced first hook so it is specific to shipping not the cart total, so rather than
`woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total`
use
`woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping`